# Error: __init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, logistic-regression, gridsearchcv

I was trying to perform regularized logistic regression with penalty = 'elasticnet' using GridSerchCV.

```
parameter_grid = {'l1_ratio': [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9]} 

GS = GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression(penalty = 'elasticnet', solver = 'saga', max_iter = 1000), parameter_grid, 'roc_auc')
```

An error of '**init**() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given' showed.

However, there were only 3 arguments. I wondered what was the problem with my code.

Comment: We're talking about [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) `GridSearchCV`? There are two positional arguments. Python says 3 because it counts `self`. I don't know what you want the `'roc_auc'` string to be used for, but it must be one of the keyword arguments, so you must say which one.

Comment: Yes. I was trying to find out the best `l1_ratio` for this regularized regression model based on `auc`. I believed the parameters are in the correct order based on the user guide of `GridSearchCV`. I am confused.

Comment: See the first `*` in `class sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV(estimator, param_grid, *, scoring=None, n_jobs=None, refit=True, cv=None, verbose=0, pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs', error_score=nan, return_train_score=False)`? Do you understand what that means? Do you know what *positional parameters* and *keyword parameters* are? Where you have written `'roc_auc'`, *which parameter is that supposed to supply*?